# projection from free module to quotient module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a confusion about the tensor product of modules. Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $M$ and $M'$ be $R$-modules. Let $R(M\times M')$ be the free module whose basis is $M\times M'$. Let $K$ be the submodule generated by the four types of elements of $M\times M'$, 1) $(m_1+m_2,m')-(m_1,m')-(m_2,m')$, 2) $(m,m_1^{'}+m_2^{'})-(m,m_1^{'})-(m,m_2^{'}), 3) $ $r(m,m')-(rm,m')$, 4) $r(m,m')-(m,rm')$. Let $\rho:R(M\times M')\to R(M\times M')/K$ be the projection map. Of course $R(M\times M')/K$ is $M\otimes M'$. Now my confusion is that $\rho$ seems to be both linear and bilinear, and therefore the zero map. It is linear because all projection maps onto quotients are linear. And it is bilinear, by the very definition of $K$. But it can't be both. So where is my mistake?

@Hugocito pointed out the $\rho$ can't be bilinear because $R(M\times M')$ is a module and not a product of two modules. But then let $i:M\times M'\to R(M\times M')$ be the inclusion map, and then $\rho \circ i:M\times M'\to M\otimes M'$ is a composition of two linear maps, which is both linear, because it is the compostion of two linear maps, and is also bilinear. So where is my mistake now?

Comment: It does not make sense to say $\rho$ is bilinear because $R(M\times M')$ is just a module, it is not the product of two modules. A map to be bilinear must be defined on the product of two modules.

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion map $i$ is neither linear nor bilinear but just a map of sets since by its very definition the basis elements in the free module $R(M\times M^\prime)$ do not satisfy any relations between each other. But by construction of $K$ the composition $\rho\circ i$ becomes bilinear. $\rho$ on the other hand is linear by construction, as was already mentioned.